# Is there a php script for extracting quotes?

Tags: php, text-extraction, quoting

I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow or google so I thought I'd ask.

I'm looking for a php script that can extract quotes from a given text. For instance, I have this text:

> Federer fully deserved his victory. Not only does it level him with
>   Sampras on seven Wimbledon titles, but also secures him a record 286th
>   week as world number one. He is the second-oldest man to occupy top
>   spot, goes away with a cheque for £1.15m. He will head to the Olympics
>   - also being staged at the All England Club - as clear favourite.

And would like to have a sentence extracted like:

> Federer fully deserved his victory.

The sentence has to make sense on its own. It cannot refer to a previous sentence, as it is a quote and is presented on its own. Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: what exactly is a quote?

Comment: How can the system (or anyone) tell which bit is supposed to be the quote?

Comment: How do you define a "quote" in your data?  If it's based on intuitive linguistic analysis, then get ready for a steep uphill climb in automated language processing.

Comment: How the quotes are marked? For parsing contents you need a regular appearing feature, like an HTML tag or actual quotes ("»)

Comment: It looks like you are looking for Artificial Intelligence. I don't think any language have any specific functions/methods for your task.

Comment: You're basically asking your computer to understand English, which anyone who has ever used a spell checker will tell you that they do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you go for the first sentence, chances are pretty good it does not "refer to a previous sentence" :)

You can use `preg_match()` for that.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

See the first answer to [First Sentence Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569091/first-sentence-regex) and the comments for some regex examples.